# shell script calls perl script but exits on perl script's completion

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I've got a bash script with a while loop that iterates over a list of directories.  On each pass, it calls a perl script to do some work.

But on the first pass, whether the perl script exits successfully or with an error, the outer shell script exits too.

I've played with the bash trap command, and searched for an answer, but no solution yet.  Thanks for any advice....

Comment: Post the code somewhere so we can see it, otherwise this is just guesswork.

Answer (score 4):

Possibilities:

1. The perl script isn't exiting with status 0 on success and `set -e` is in effect.
2. The bash script is executing the perl script with `exec`

Comment: The shell script doesn't use `set -e` but I've explicitly tried `set +e` just  before calling the perl script, and there's no difference.  
The shell script calls the perl script without any exec, ie:
    `/usr/local/bin/MyPerlScript MyParam1 MyParam2`